# Is there any module for Non_Linear Logistic regression in Python sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In the package `sklearn` available here - [Github/Sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn) we see `linear_model` module which is very well used for `logistic regression` ML problems. I'm successful in implementing that for datasets, decision boundary of which can be separated by a straight line. But the question is how can one implement logisitc regression for `non-linear models`.

I tried searching the library (in the above guithub link) if it contains any relevant module, but couldn't. Is there a way to deal with non-linear problems from sklearn? (apart from clustering algorithms) Are there any other library to help with non-linear regression ? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you know that logistic regression is not a regression model? It is a classifier.

Comment: You are talking regression, but your shown example is a classification and also LogisticRegression is a classifier. There are several estimators in scikit, which are non linear, like Support vector machines.

Answer (score 5):

One way you can do it is adding the non-linear features you think you'll need to your data set. For example if you think quadratic terms in one variable will help (they'll let you fit orthogonal ellipses), then append x^2, y^2, ... columns to your data matrix of x, y, ... . Then run linear methods on this.

Comment: Nice, but as you said "one way of doing", so is this a workaround or there is any standard way of doing it?

Comment: This is a standard approach. `sklearn` has a dedicated `PolynomialFeatures` class for this purpose.

Comment: Great then ,  :)